# Сокращение текста в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

я делаю запрос, но мне нужно что бы выводился текст
не весь что там ечть а только первые 4 рядка или как-то по количеству слов
подскажите кто знает как это реализовать.

```
Select name, description
from table
Where id=8
```

Comment: Ну так сделай это не средствами скл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 4 name, description
FROM table
WHERE id=8
```

выберет первые 4 строки из таблицы, которые подходят под заданные условия(WHERE id=8)

Comment: В Mysql нет TOP.

Comment: а limit ???

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего выводить количество символов, например, 100:

```
substr(description, 1, 100)
```

Чтобы не обрывать слово, можно продолжить, например, до ближайшего пробела (или точки и т.п.):

```
substr(name,1,instr(substr(description,100),' ')+1)
```